# PL/SQL: Cursor doubles the last record from the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created the following PL/SQL anonymous block. The cursor below retrieves data from the select statement:

```
select mod_benutzer, count(*) 
  from dok_auspraegung 
 where parent_objekt_id = 1093 
 group by mod_benutzer;
```

This statement displays exactly two records:

```
DDMS_USER |  8    
HU2MAMU   | 14
```

But when I want to display these two records by cursor, it displays "HU2MAMU|14" two times like below:

Modifications:

```
DDMS_USER, 8x    
HU2MAMU, 14x    
HU2MAMU, 14x
```

```
declare
    my_exception_1          exception;
    var_parent_objekt_id    dok_auspraegung.parent_objekt_id%TYPE := 1093;
    var_date                varchar(30);
    var_mod_benutzer        varchar2(10);
    var_benutzer_modifs     number;
    
    cursor cursor_dok_auspraegung 
    is select mod_benutzer, count(*) from dok_auspraegung 
    where parent_objekt_id = 10935797565
    group by mod_benutzer;
begin
    select distinct to_char(mod_datum,'YYYY-MON-DD') into var_date from dok_auspraegung where parent_objekt_id = var_parent_objekt_id;
    
    IF var_date is not null THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Parent Object ID' || ': ' || var_parent_objekt_id);
        dbms_output.put_line('Date: ' || '            ' || var_date);
    ELSE RAISE my_exception_1;
    END IF;
    
    open cursor_dok_auspraegung;
    
    dbms_output.put_line('Modifications:');
    loop
        fetch cursor_dok_auspraegung into var_mod_benutzer, var_benutzer_modifs;
            dbms_output.put(var_mod_benutzer);
            dbms_output.put_line(', ' || var_benutzer_modifs || 'x');
        exit when cursor_dok_auspraegung%notfound;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(cursor_dok_auspraegung%rowcount);
    
    close cursor_dok_auspraegung;
exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
        dbms_output.put_line('Parent Object ID not found!');
    when my_exception_1 then
        dbms_output.put_line('');
end;
```

What is the reason of that?

Answer (score 4):

Because exiting from the cursor occurs after printing the value of the variables in the current case, this repeats the last value to be printed. So, it should occur before printing as follows

```
loop
    fetch cursor_dok_auspraegung into var_mod_benutzer, var_benutzer_modifs;
    exit when cursor_dok_auspraegung%notfound;
        dbms_output.put(var_mod_benutzer);
        dbms_output.put_line(', ' || var_benutzer_modifs || 'x');        
end loop;
```